# servo retaining its position everytime i send some value

Tags: arduino, bluetooth, servo, hc-05

i wanted to control my servo with bluetooth modue. I gave certain values for rotating it. but when i press those values the servo rotates but then retains it's original position and pc pc also make the sound of arduino board disconnecting because i powered the board with my pc(tried with powerbank also)

this is my code

```
#include <Servo.h>
Servo myservo;
int pos = 0;
char data = 0;                
void setup() {
  myservo.attach(9);
  Serial.begin(9600);}
void loop(){
  if(Serial.available() > 0){ 
    data = Serial.read();             
    if(data == 'F'){        
//         for (pos = 0; pos <= 180; pos += 1) even this line dosent work
         myservo.write(180);
         delay(1);
        }}
    else if(data == 'B'){     
//       for (pos = 180; pos >= 0; pos -= 1)  even this line dosent work
         myservo.write(0); 
         delay(1);
        }}
```

connections
servo
red wire -- 5v (not working in 3.3 v)
orange wire --  pin9
brown wire -- gnd

bluetooth (hc05)
5v -- 5v
gnd -- gnd
rx -- tx
tx -- rx

Answer (score 1):

Your `else if (data=='B'){` is in the wrong place - it's part of the `if(Serial.available() > 0) {` condition - instead of the `if(data == 'F'){` condition. Notice the double `}}` in the line before.

I've corrected the code and reformated it so you can clearly see the matching opening and closing braces.

This works on [Tinkercad Circuits](https://www.tinkercad.com/things/1RrPW56N0CN) passing commands through the serial monitor - so imagine it would work fine taking commands from bluetooth.

```
#include <Servo.h>

Servo myservo;
int pos = 0;
char data = 0;                

void setup() {
  myservo.attach(9);
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  
  if(Serial.available() > 0) { 

    data = Serial.read();             

    if(data == 'F'){ 
      for (pos = 0; pos <= 180; pos += 1) {
         myservo.write(pos);
         delay(1);
      }
    }
    else if(data == 'B'){ 
      for (pos = 180; pos >= 0; pos -= 1) {
         myservo.write(pos); 
         delay(1);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: that dint solve my error i am face the same error

Comment: Have you tried running this whilst connecting to your computer and sending the commands through the Serial monitor, rather than Bluetooth? Also - how have you set up the HC05 - normally it defaults to 38400 baud? I think the code looks alright - although you may want to setup a Software Serial port for the bluetooth so you can send debug through the standard serial port. You may find you get a better response from the [Arduino Stack Exchange](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/) site as they're likely to help with the bluetooth connectivity.

Comment: doing it with computer also dosent work

Comment: Sounds like it's not a programming issue then so you would be better off posting to the arduino site. Are you using a micro servo or something bigger? It's possible it's drawing too much power from the Arduino causing it to reset?